# What is the difference between incipient, nascent, onset?

Tags: meaning, etymology, synonyms

I am having some real problems seeing some differences among these three words. All three of them deal with a beginning,birthing or coming into existence of some thing or process. My understanding of incipient so far is that it seems  to refer to something currently at the initial stages of drawn out process that goes from simple to complex before it finally comes into full maturity ( so this word kind of being close to embryonic). Nascent seems to me to refer to something already in full mature form but is just born, not a long time ago, while onset seems to be continuous existence and influence of something. But even with this understanding, I am still not sure if I cam interpreting the definitions right. So if anyone can help me out explaining these three words, it would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful. If it was, please upvote and (if you see fit) accept it.  I'd be happy to clarify anything if you need me to!

Answer (score 2):

The three words have the same fundamental meaning, but there are some distinctions between them.

*Please note that "incipient" and "nascent" are adjectives, whereas "onset" is a noun.*

---

**"Incipient" is defined as:**

> In an initial stage; beginning to happen or develop. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/incipient)]

Therefore, "incipient" should be used to describe things that are **"immature" or "emerging."**

**"Nascent" is defined as:**

> (especially of a process or organization) just coming into existence and beginning to display signs of future potential. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nascent)]

Therefore, "nascent" should be used to describe things that are **"budding" or "embryonic."**

**"Onset" is defined as:**

> The beginning of something, especially something unpleasant. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/onset)]

Therefore, "onset" is synonymous with **"rise" or "inception," but it has a negative connotation.**

---

Overall, these are the **key details** I would associate with each word:

1. Incipient - new and initially undeveloped
2. Nascent - new, but showing potential; "budding"
3. Onset - beginning, but usually foreboding